# Android how to pass image from image view and text from text from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi in android i know how to send image from one activity to another and send text from text view to another,separately. But i want to know in an activity we have both text view and image view.But my need is i want to send both text and image from one activity to another.Any suggestions is welcomed. 
Thank you.

Comment: which type of image you have? bitmap or drawable?

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("text_contents", string);
b.putInt("Image View",R.drawable.image_resource);
intent.putExtra(b);

getIntent.getExtra.getString("text_content");
getIntent.getExtra.getInt("Image View");

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sending along an image? For passing a string, use Intent extras and Bundle.

In your first activity...

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);   
        intent.putExtra("text_contents", someTextView.getText().toString();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the second activity onCreate(), you retrieve the intent extras you passed via Bundle...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String someString = bundle.getString("text_contents");
    }
}
```

If your "image" is an R.drawable resource, then you could simply add that as well to the intent extras:

```
intent.putExtra("image_resource", R.drawable.some_image_resource);
```

And retrieve it from the Bundle like:

```
int someImageResource = bundle.getInt("image_resource");
```

And from there you can apply it to some ImageView:

```
someImageView.setImageResource(someImageResource);
```

**EDIT:** made a slight correction + if your "image" is a bitmap, then see Anjali's answer.